# SQLite: CASE with EXISTS on INSERT

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, case, exists

I've got a DB with three tables where one is a junction table containing foreign key references to the two other tables. I'm having trouble understanding how to make an `INSERT` statement to the junction table conditional on matching rows existing in the other two tables, as follows:

schoolB_courses:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
course_prefix TEXT, 
course_number INTEGER, 
course_title TEXT, 
course_credits INTEGER, 
course_requisites TEXT, 
course_notes TEXT, 
course_description TEXT, 
course_url TEXT)
```

schoolA_courses:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
course_prefix TEXT, 
course_number INTEGER, 
course_title TEXT, 
course_credits INTEGER, 
course_requisites TEXT, 
course_notes TEXT, 
course_description TEXT)
```

schoolB_equivalencies:

```
equivalency_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
schoolA_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
schoolB_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
is_archived INTEGER NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (schoolA_id) REFERENCES schoolA_courses (id), 
FOREIGN KEY (schoolB_id) REFERENCES schoolB_courses (id))
```

Given a user input for `schoolA.course_prefix`, `schoolA.course_number`, `schoolB.course_prefix`, and `schoolB.course_number`, I understand how to perform an insert into the `schoolB_equivalencies` table:

```
INSERT INTO schoolB_equivalencies (schoolA_id, schoolB_id, is_archived) 
VALUES ( (SELECT id from schoolA_courses WHERE course_number=? AND course_prefix=?),
(SELECT id from schoolB_courses WHERE course_number=? AND course_prefix=?),0)
```

But **how could I only perform this `INSERT` *only* if there is a row in `schoolA_courses` with a matching course number and prefix, AND a row in `schoolB_courses` with a matching course number and prefix** (to prevent equivalency inserts where either the schoolA course, the schoolB course, or both don't exist)?

**I've tried putting together a CASE statement, but SO won't allow me to post it (I get a generic "problem occurred" message when I try to include it in this question)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply execute the two SELECTs separately, and then execute the INSERT only when needed.

But if you really want to use a single statement, this is possible.
The [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) has two forms: with VALUES, which inserts a fixed number of rows, and with SELECT, which insert as many rows as are returned by the query.
So you have to construct a SELECT query that returns no row if there are no matching courses:

```
INSERT INTO schoolB_equivalencies (schoolA_id, schoolB_id, is_archived)
SELECT schoolA_courses.id,
       schoolB_courses.id,
       0
FROM schoolA_courses,
     schoolB_courses
WHERE schoolA_courses.course_number = ?
  AND schoolA_courses.course_prefix = ?
  AND schoolB_courses.course_number = ?
  AND schoolB_courses.course_prefix = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks! Was not aware of the other form of `SELECT` as I'm pretty new to SQL - I'll read up on it.